# Why are signed distances needed in euclidean geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am taking a course in euclidean and non-euclidean geometry, and therefore came across some fundamental theorems and definitions in euclidean geometry.

As an introduction to theorems such as Ceva's theorem, I was taught the definitions of signed lengths.
For example:

> Take a euclidean line, and equip it with a positive direction. For two
> point on the line, $B$ and $C$, we say $BC>0$ if $C$ is located 'after'
> $B$ on the line.

And similarly for negative lengths. I was wondering what exactly is the purpose of these definitions, as I don't see how they change anything about our theorems. They cause Menelaus' theorem to include the condition:

$$\frac{AF}{FB}\cdot \frac{BD}{DC} \cdot \frac{CE}{EA} = -1$$

Which doesn't only seem a bit odd, but, to me, doesn't seem to add anything to the version of the theorem with the standard lengths multiplying to $1$.

So why do we even bother defining these signed lengths? Is this a particular case of a more general idea in geometry? Does it somehow slightly strengthen some theorems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would Menelaus' Theorem remain true if the right side was $+1$? If not, then by necessity the distances referred to on the left are signed.

Comment: The sign in the theorem adds information: an odd number of the three factors is negative, and this translates into information about how the points are placed. Why would you prefer not to have that information?

Comment: So the only purpose is to tell us the order of the points? Why can't we simply add the order of the points instead of introducing  a new concept of signed lengths

Comment: It was what Euclid's geometry had done for 2 thousand years. We could have staid with non-signed distances. In fact your question has to be seen in the context of the huge revolution in "classical" geometry that has taken place in the 19th century, changing the face of Euclidean geometry. The systematic introduction of signed quantities (oriented distances, bu also oriented angles) mainly due to M. Chasles, has brought **simplification** and **generalization** at the price of a (small) supplementary abstraction, which is a general trend in mathematics !

Comment: [Ctd] **Simplication** : results presented before with different "case studies", necessitate only one figure. **Generalization**: a typical case is the two **non-euclidean geometries** : without the introduction of **negative** quantities and even **complex** quantities to which a geometric meaning can be attached, they couldn' have been "invented"...